# Raspberry Pi - No Module named 'RPI' (although installed)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-import

I have just bought my first ever Raspberry. 
Naturally I want to try some of the example projects provided in the book that I have gotten with it.

The code requires me to import RPI.GPIO but fails to run because there is no module named RPI.
When I try to install it with `sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio` (I have gotten the command from another post) It says that RPI is already installed and up-to-date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have to tried to reinstall the raspberry OS that I downloaded from their website as well as the command from [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60774/importerror-no-module-named-rpi) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. To anyone else wondering.

Please be sure to look at the casing as that is important.
After changing RP>I< to RP>i< it worked. Thank you anyways!

Comment: you are a Savior